# pyspark: how to group N records in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV with 5 million records, with the structure:

```
+----------+------------+------------+
|  row_id  |    col1    |    col2    |
+----------+------------+------------+
|         1|   value    |    value   |
|         2|   value    |    value   |
|....                                |
|...                                 |
|   5000000|   value    |    value   |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

I need to convert this CSV to JSON with each json-file having 500 records and a particular structure like this:

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "row_id": "1",
            "col1": "value",
            "col2": "value"
        },
        {
            "row_id": "2",
            "col1": "value",
            "col2": "value"
        },
        ....
        ..
        {
            "row_id": "500",
            "col1": "value",
            "col2": "value"
        }
    ],
    "last_updated":"09-09-2021T01:03:04.44Z"
}
```

Using **PySpark** I am able to read the csv and create a dataframe.  I don't know how to group 500 records in a single json of the structure `"entry": [ <500 records> ],"last_updated":"09-09-2021T01:03:04.44Z"`
I can use `df.coalesce(1).write.option("maxRecordsPerFile",500)` but that will give me only the set of 500 records, without any structure.  I want those 500 records in the `"entry"` list and `"last_updated"` following it (which I am taking from `datetime.now()`).

Comment: Please update your question with sample rows from your dataframe/csv file so that your structure can be inferred and a reproducible sample may be created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the following:

---

NB. I've used the following imports.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
```

---

**1**. We need a column that can be used to split your data in 500 record batches

*(Recommended)* We can create a pseudo column to achieve this with `row_number`

```py
df = df.withColumn("group_num",(F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("row_id"))-1) % 500 )
```

otherwise, if `row_id` starting at `1` is consistently increasing in the 5 million records, we may use that

```py
df = df.withColumn("group_num",(F.col("row_id")-1) % 500 )
```

or in that odd chance that the column `"last_updated":"09-09-2021T01:03:04.44Z"` is unique to each batch of 500 records

```py
df = df.withColumn("group_num",F.col("last_updated"))
```

---

**2**. We will transform your dataset by grouping  by the `group_num`

```py
df = (
    df.groupBy("group_num")
      .agg(
          F.collect_list(
              F.expr("struct(row_id,col1,col2)")
          ).alias("entries")
      )
      .withColumn("last_updated",F.lit(datetime.now())))
      .drop("group_num")
)
```

NB. If you would like to include all columns you may use `F.expr("struct(*)")` instead of `F.expr("struct(row_id,col1,col2)")`.

---

**3**. Finally you can write to your output/destination with the option [`.option("maxRecordsPerFile",1)`](http://www.gatorsmile.io/anticipated-feature-in-spark-2-2-max-records-written-per-file/) since each row now stores at most 500 entries

Eg.

```py
df.write.format("json").option("maxRecordsPerFile",1).save("<your intended path here>")
```

---

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: edited the question with CSV structure.

Comment: @aiman I've updated the answer, let me know if this works for you.